# How do I fix this error, "Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found."?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have this function with firebase but I keep getting the error message stating "Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found." with the items in the quotes in the lines with "snapshot.docs[0].data('Quote') as String?"

How can I fix this, any help is appreciated!

```
Future getNewsPostDetails(String newsPostId) async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('newsPosts')
        .where('newsPostId', isEqualTo: newsPostId)
        .get();
    newsPostDetails newPostDetails = newsPostDetails(
      newsPostTitle: snapshot.docs[0].data('newsPostTitle') as String?,
      newsPostAuthor: snapshot.docs[0].data('newsPostAuthor') as String?,
      newsPostContent: snapshot.docs[0].data('newsPostContent') as String?,
      date: snapshot.docs[0].data('date') as String?,
    );
    return newPostDetails;
  }
```

Here is the newsPostDetails.dart

```
class newsPostDetails {
  final String? newsPostTitle;
  final String? newsPostAuthor;
  final String? newsPostContent;
  final String? date;

  newsPostDetails(
      {this.newsPostTitle,
      this.newsPostAuthor,
      this.newsPostContent,
      this.date});
}
```

Comment: You should check the length of the snapshot.docs array before indexing into it.  It could be empty, in which case, your code will crash.

Comment: How might I be able to do that?

Comment: Try a web search asking the question of what I just suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'data()' function does not expect any arguments. The 'data()' function returns the map back. You can access the information you want from the map.

```dart
Future getNewsPostDetails(String newsPostId) async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('newsPosts')
        .where('newsPostId', isEqualTo: newsPostId)
        .get();
    final newPostData = snapshot.docs[0].data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
    newsPostDetails newPostDetails = newsPostDetails(
      newsPostTitle: newPostData['newsPostTitle'] as String?,
      newsPostAuthor: newPostData['newsPostAuthor'] as String?,
      newsPostContent: newPostData['newsPostContent'] as String?,
      date: newPostData['date'] as String?,
    );
    return newPostDetails;
  }
```

Comment: Its good, but now I get the error "The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')." right before the brackets. Adding a ! doesn't work.

Comment: Updated my answer, check, please